# How to setup the aliases in unix using the script file?

Tags: unix, aliases

I want to add all my aliase in a g.ksh file like

```
alias outbox="cd /var/uhs/xys/abc"
alias 1outbox="cd /var/uhs/xys/ab1"
alias 2outbox="cd /var/uhs/xys/ab2"
alias o3utbox="cd /var/uhs/xys/ab3"
alias 4outbox="cd /var/uhs/xys/ab4"
alias 5out="cd /var/uhs/xys/ab5"
```

and then i need to add it to my profile.

Comment: So what is not working here?

Comment: i created the file now what are the next steps to do?

Answer (score 0):

its working 
i have done the following steps
1) created a file with name g.ksh placed in home directory.
2) run the command alias gaurav='. g.ksh'
3)typed gaurav and enter.
4)now alias names outbox,1outbox are working

now the thing is if i will logout from the session then i am logging in again i need to do all these steps again

all i just want is as soon as i login to the server it should load automatically.